# Alternate vs alternative

Tags: word-usage, difference

What is the difference between these two sentences? Do they mean the same?

> an alternate method of payment
>
> an alternative method of payment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In many cases, including this one, 'alternate' and 'alternative' can be used to mean the same thing, where both describe a choice apart from what is first offered: an alternate viewpoint; an alternative suggestion.

There are situations where 'alternate' only is used - when we mean 'happening by turns', first one thing then the other, possibly repeated: in alternate weeks, I work in the office and at home.

[Alternate vs alternative (Merriam-Webster)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/differences-between-alternate-and-alternative)